# How to display pagination in following formate?

Tags: pagination

I want to display Pagination in following format

page first entry to page last entry of total entry

example : in first page i want to display 10 entry so i want to following output

1 to 10 of 100

this can be possible ? if possible please guide me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can do most of this with the default [EE pagination tags](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html), but I think in order to get the last number of the entries on the page you should check out the [AB Pagination add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ab-pagination). Using that add-on makes outputting pagination like "1 to 10 of 100" easy.